# kill -9 not working from bash script but works in console

Tags: bash, kill

I have two script one starts appium an makes it run in background the other kills it (or that is what it should do).

start_appium.sh:

```
nohup node $APPIUM --nodeconfig $CONFIG_PATH -a $IP_ADDRESS --port $APPIUM_PORT --chromedriver-port $CHROME_DRIVER_PORT --log $LOG_FILE > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

kill_all_appiums.sh:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'appium' | awk '{print $2}')
```

The kill script however doesn't work when executed. If I copy the same kill command and directly execute it in terminal, it does work. Why is that and how can I fix it?

PS: I am on a Mac don't know how relevant that is.

Comment: You may want to make sure that `grep` does not find itself... or use `killall`.

Comment: @AlexP I don't think the `grep` matters it will try to kill a pid that doesn't exist. I made sure not to find `grep` and it is still the same. Just `kill` and `killall` do not work even from terminal.

Comment: actually, a kill of the grep, if it happens could impact the pipe sequence. A simple test would be to add "grep -v grep" after the grep appium

Comment: @MichaelFelt yes as stated I added it anyway. The problem was that the script kills itself before killing the process. Because the bash script greps itself.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR My script kills itself before killing the Appium process.

The problem was in the name of my script containing appium in its name. The code `$(ps aux | grep 'appium' | awk '{print $2}')` gets the pid of the /bin/bash that is running the /path/to/kill_appiums.sh script. And then it seems that it kills the script that should be killing the appium process. Then there is no one to kill the appium process and it remains active :)

Comment: You "shame" us so-called smart|alert readers. We should have spotted the script name as well! Thanks for the reminder to re-read the question!